# Paste special values using a script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am a beginner and need to write a simple script to paste special values in Google Sheets. I tried the below script, but it's not working.

```
function livedata_Function() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Live_Data");
    spreadsheet.getRange('L3:T1378').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("K3"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine. Perhaps the cells in the target range already have some formats that get automatically applied to the data that you paste as values only?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.